# Health checks for an API server on Google Cloud Run

Tags: serverless, google-cloud-run, health-check

I'm looking into using Google Cloud Run to host an API server. From what I've been able to find, **it looks like Cloud Run does not have the ability to perform periodic health checks and restart unhealthy instances**. Is that right?

I would have thought this would be important for longer running processes. What are the best practices to make sure my service stays healthy over time with something like Cloud Run?

Answer (score 2):

> it looks like Cloud Run does not have the ability to perform periodic
> health checks and restart unhealthy instances. Is that right?

The answer depends on what you mean by health check and by longer running process.

The GFE performs a simple health check, called readiness checks, on your Cloud Run service and will terminate a non-responsive container. This test is limited to making sure your container responds on the listening TCP port.

Google Cloud Monitoring provides uptime checks and alerts for Cloud Run but no method to restart unhealthy instances.

- [Cloud Run Monitoring Health and Performance](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/monitoring)
- [Create public uptime checks](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks)

How do you test a long-running process? Each request to Cloud Run is independent. That means any container instance can process the HTTP request. There is no method to specify which container is tested short of setting the max instances to one.

Another issue arises when your health check determines your service is down. How do you terminate a container? You could call an endpoint that then executes `os.exit(1)`, but you have no control over which container will process that HTTP request.

When I am not enabling **Always-on CPU**, I don't worry about special health checks. If my service is idle, then a health check will cold start an instance which increases costs.

A strategy I use with **Always-on CPU** is to have my Cloud Run service send heartbeats to another service. The other service monitors those heartbeats and sends an alert when a threshold is exceeded.

In summary, there is no simple method to verify that a long-running Cloud Run process is functioning via standard health checks. You can test the service, just not individual processes. Your process will need to notify something else periodically to report status.

Comment: Thank you John. Is the readiness check performed periodically on an instance or only on startup? The problems you mentioned in not being able to test or restart individual instances are what I was concerned about. It seems like App Engine Flex might be an alternative with more robust health checking. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @RahulSekhar - I am not sure about the frequency of readiness checks from a technical design perspective. You can see them in the Cloud Run logs and I have only noticed them on container start.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer, but liveness and startup probe have recently been introduced to cloud run. Here's the doc:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks

Comment: It is usually good to write answers as intemporal, using phrases like "by the time of writing this, this has just been added...". Also, maybe the original question is not looking for an answer but a random person from the internet is, better to avoid that kind of sentences as well :)